# Removing node in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I just started getting into nodes and simple linked lists. While I find linked lists confusing I still start to understand them more and can code them following different tutorials.

But to remove nodes I tried a piece of code that didn't quite work and found another one that did. Except I don't quite get why one works and the other doesn't.

Here is what doesn't work:

```
void remove_character(Character **head)
{
Character *current=*head,
    *temp=malloc(sizeof(Character));//temporary node to 
     //remove node
char *name=malloc(100);

if(current!=NULL)//if there is at least one node
{
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
}

if(!strcmp(name, (*head)->name))//removes head and 
//makes next node head
{
    temp=(*head);
    (*head)=(*head)->next;
    free(temp->name);
    free(temp);
    current=*head;
}

while(current!=NULL)
{
       if(!strcmp(name, current->name))
    {
        temp=current;//assign node to be removed
        current=current->next;//move to next node
        free(temp->name);
        free(temp);//free removed node
    }
    current=current->next;
}
}
```

But this works:

```
void remove_character(Character **head)
{
Character *current=*head, 
  *temp=malloc(sizeof(Character));
char *name=malloc(100);

if(current!=NULL)
{
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
}

if(!strcmp(name, (*head)->name))
{
    temp=(*head);
    (*head)=(*head)->next;
    free(temp->name);
    free(temp);
    current=*head;
}

while(current!=NULL)
{
    if(current->next!=NULL)
    {
        if(!strcmp(name, current->next->name))
        {//if next node is node to be removed
            temp=current->next;
            current->next=current->next->next;
                            //moves to next node
            free(temp->name);
            free(temp);
        }
    }
    current=current->next;
}
}
```

Basically the second one anticipates one node and links one node further but why should this one work and not the other (which prints segmentation fault right where the removed node was... Nodes seem so easy but are so complicated to manage. Especially when you are bad at imagining how it works.

Comment: "Especially when you are bad at imagining how it works." Draw a visual of a linked list out on paper then so you aren't needing to imagine it. I had a whiteboard next to my desk to draw on until I could visualize it unaided. As the question stands though, this is far too broad for SO.

Comment: Note: both of them leak memory. You allocate memory for `temp` and then throw it away by assigning another pointer to it. Don’t allocate memory. As for why First doesn’t work, it doesn’t remove anything from the chain. Just frees memory and leaves dangling pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first method you are not proactive.

*That is you check for the `string` after visiting the particular `node` and once you found the `node` which is to be deleted you just `free` it and move further without fixing the `list`.*

Adding one more `pointer` to point the previous `node` should fix this issue.

```
        if(!strcmp(name, (*head)->name))
        {
            /* Code to delete in the head node */ 

            temp=(*head);
            (*head)=(*head)->next;
            free(temp->name);
            free(temp);
            current=*head;
        }
        else 
        {

            /* Code to delete in the rest of the list*/ 
            character *prev=*head;
            while(current!=NULL)
            {
                if(!strcmp(name, current->name))
                {
                    prev->next = current->next;//move to next node
                    free(current->name);
                    free(current);//free removed node
                    break;
                }
                prev = current;
                current=current->next;
            }
        }
```

In your second method you are proactive.

*That is you check for the `string` before visiting the particular `node` and once you found out  that next `node` which is to be deleted then you `free` it and  move further after fixing the `list`.*

```
if(!strcmp(name, current->next->name))   // Found out next node to be deleted
{
     temp=current->next;                 // Get the next node
     current->next=current->next->next;  // Adjust the list by skipping the next node

     free(temp->name);                   // Free the node.
     free(temp);
}
```

Comment: This line `prev->next = current->next;` will work fine with nodes but the first node will cause a problem when you remove it.

Comment: @LionKing I was concentrating on deleting in the rest of the list.Anyway I have edited the code.